# Speed up AWS Redshift spectrum select

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have an `airflow` dag which reads some `json` data and split into different `parquet` files that are uploaded to `AWS S3`.

I have the specific path partitioned by 5 values which are:

1. type
2. year
3. month
4. day
5. hour

Then I do a SELECT statement such as:

```
SELECT fields 
FROM table
WHERE type='A' 
AND year='2020'
AND month='11'
AND day='25'
AND hour='20'
```

But it takes around 2 minutes per each `type` `S3` path, and I have 30 and still growing.

I read that to speed up you have to use following:

- Parquet - Done
- Fewest column possible - Done (I have a lot, but are the minimum I need)
- Use less parquet files, around 64mb each. And I had 168 files of few `kb` before trying to merge them in a single one of around 1 mb.

This last option didn't speed it up. So I don't know how to improve the process speed. It is an hourly job, and it takes 50 minutes to insert the 30 folders data into `Redshift` tables.

The data is already `partitioned by`:

If I use:

```
select *
from SVV_EXTERNAL_PARTITIONS
where tablename='table' and schemaname='spectrum'
and values='["A","2020","11","25","20"]';
```

It returns a row:

```
spectrum,table,"[""A"",""2020"",""11"",""25"",""20""]",s3://parquet/account/A/2020/11/25/20/,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe,{},0,{}
```

Comment: Is your data partitioned into separate paths? For example, is all `2020` data in a separate file and folder?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, 2020 data is splitted by month, day and hour. And the full path is added to the PARTITIONED BY statement as I attached in the post.

Comment: Those directory names don't look like a normal Hive-style partitioning. That would normally have directory names like `year=2020/month=11/day=25/`. Have you tested whether the partitioning is working correctly? For example, if you query for `year=2030`, does it return instantly because there is no data for that partition? And are those year/month/day fields really strings, not numbers? Just trying to help you figure out what is happening.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein mmm you're right using where year=2030 takes a lot of time too. Around 2 minutes again...

If I search the table into AWS Glue console and i go to partitions I see the partitions as partition_0, partition_1, and partition_2, partition_3. It is as I query them, the year, month and other naming convention I used was to provide better understanding.

Comment: The question here is, does partition_0 and others look like a normal Hive-style partitioning? Or do I have to reformat them? If its the case its only to add the partition_name= in the folder name in s3?

Comment: Have you found out what caused the slowdown?

Comment: @Balint i post now an answer

Answer (score 1):

I expect you need to use the PARTITION BY option in the external table definition.  Just having the S3 key path with keywords in it doesn't tell Redshift Spectrum what data is in each folder.  So Redshift has to read all the files looking for the data you want.  You may need to change the keypaths to your files so that they conform to the S3 partition syntax.

A good example of doing this is at "Example 2: Partitioning with a multiple partition key" in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c-spectrum-external-tables.html

Comment: It's already in use. I attached the query I run to check partition is set up okei in the table.

Comment: Your object naming doesn't support partitioning.  You need to have YEAR=2020 in your keypath not just 2020.  You then define your external table with PARTITION of YEAR and Spectrum can reduce the number of objects it needs to scan.

Answer (score 1):

Set of things to do. Here the checklist:

1. Ensure you are using hive partitioning. Not needed the `year=2020` format as said in some answer. Hive partitioning works using only 2020. If you don't use the `year=2020` naming the partition it's named `partition_n` where n is a number.
2. Check data volume for some partitions. It's better to have less files, and bigger ones (parquet) than otherwise.
3. Split data in significant buckets. In my case I work with 4 providers. And each of them are expected to grom in data volume, then I did 4 bucekts instead of one where first partition was the provider.